# Clear EditText value in a RecyclerView row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my android project. There I am adding rows from searching from a `AutoCompleteTextView`. Each row has `TextView` and one `EditText` field. As well as adding, I am also removing rows. I have a remove button in a each row.

Everything works fine. Problem is I cannot clear `EditText` value in removing. For example if I add three rows and remove the second one, the third row should come to second place with its own `EditText` value. But the problem is, the value from the row removed is not clearing and the third row's `EditText` value is replaced by it instead. Then if I add another row (to the third place), automatically  that `EditText` field is filled with previous third row's `EditText` value.

How can I clear `EditText` value also???

This is my adapter code.

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<String> itemsName, itemsQty, itemsPCode, itemPlant, _retData;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private String[] mDataset;
    public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;
    private String[] arrayForSaveEditTextValue;

    public SelectItemAdapter(Context context, String[] mDataset) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsPCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemPlant = new ArrayList<String>();
        _retData = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.arrayForSaveEditTextValue = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_selected_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));
        holder.setItemQty(itemsQty.get(position));
        holder.setItemPCode(itemsPCode.get(position));
        holder.setItemPlant(itemPlant.get(position));
        holder.numPicker.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                _retData.set(position, arg0.toString());
                Log.d("arg0",arg0.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public String retrieveData(int i) {
        return _retData.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsName.size();
    }

    public Object getItemName(int position) {
        return itemsName.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemQty(int position) {
        return itemsQty.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPCode(int position) {
        return itemsPCode.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPlant(int position) {
        return itemPlant.get(position);
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public void add(int location, String iName, String iQty, String iPCode, String iPlant) {
        itemsName.add(location, iName);
        itemsQty.add(location, iQty);
        itemsPCode.add(location, iPCode);
        itemPlant.add(location, iPlant);
        _retData.add(location,"0");
        notifyItemInserted(location);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int location) {
        if (location >= itemsName.size())
            return;

        itemsName.remove(location);
        itemsQty.remove(location);
        itemsPCode.remove(location);
        itemPlant.remove(location);
        _retData.remove(location);
        notifyItemRemoved(location);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private SelectItemAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName, txtPCode, txtAvailableQty, txtTempQty, txtPlant;
        Button bRemove;
        EditText numPicker;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, SelectItemAdapter parent) {
            super(itemView);
            this.parent = parent;
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtAvailableQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailbleQty);
            txtPCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPCode);
            txtPlant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlant);
            bRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
            numPicker = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            bRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItemName(CharSequence name) {
            textItemName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemQty(CharSequence name) {
            txtAvailableQty.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPCode(CharSequence name) {
            txtPCode.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPlant(CharSequence name) {
            txtPlant.setText(name);
        }

        public CharSequence getItemName() {
            return textItemName.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public class RetItem {
        public String _itemNumPic;
    }
}
```

And the remove method...

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Remove " + " : " + item.getItemName(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.remove(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a list of an `Object` instead of using lots of `string arrays`!
and then to achieve the behavior you want, you need to remove the item from the main list and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here is an ex:

```
List<DayEntity> days = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is a list of day items, you set this list to your adapter like this:

```
MyDayAdapter adapter = new MyDayAdapter(context, days);
```

So for removing an item in position 'x' you can do this way:

```
days.remove(x);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

have fun...

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a model class for your data, with all your getters and setters in one list:

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<MyData> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

2- remove at method

```
//Remove from the list on click
    private void removeAt(int position) {
        mUserList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataList.size());
    }
```

3- Now inside onClick() method you can call removeAt method, and you just pass the position which is the adapter position

```
             removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the values entered in the `EditText` of your `RecyclerView`. You've an array named `arrayForSaveEditTextValue` for saving the `EditText` values I think, but I see no usage of it. Your code is a little bit clumsy too. So I would like to suggest a different approach of implementing this list for you.

Create an object for your list items.

```
public class ListItem {
    public String itemsName;
    public String itemsQty; 
    public String itemsPCode;
    public String itemPlant;
    public String _retData;
    public String editTextValue = ""; // Default EditText Value
}
```

And your adapter should look like this.

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SelectItemAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> listItems) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_selected_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ListItem tempListItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.textItemName.setText(tempListItem.itemsName);
        holder.txtAvailableQty.setText(tempListItem.itemsQty);
        holder.txtPCode.setText(tempListItem.itemsPCode);
        holder.txtPlant.setText(tempListItem.itemPlant);

        holder.numPicker.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                // Calculate your _retData and set the TextView
                tempListItem._retData = calculateRetData(position, arg0.toString());
                tempListItem.editTextValue = arg0.toString();

                // Replace the item with the value updated
                listItems.add(position, tempListItem);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public void add(ListItem listItem) {
        listItems.add(listItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int location) {
        if (location >= listItems.size())
            return;

        listItems.remove(location);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private SelectItemAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName, txtPCode, txtAvailableQty, txtTempQty, txtPlant;
        Button bRemove;
        EditText numPicker;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, SelectItemAdapter parent) {
            super(itemView);
            this.parent = parent;
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtAvailableQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailbleQty);
            txtPCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPCode);
            txtPlant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlant);
            bRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
            numPicker = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            bRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to save the `EditText` value in the corresponding object and in case of adding and deleting an item from the `RecyclerView`, you have to update the list of the items accordingly and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I haven't tested the code, but I think you get the idea. Please let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.

Comment: thatnk u for the reply, i will try this.. what is **calculateRetData** in Textwatcher method???

Comment: Its just a placeholder for the method `setRetData` that you used. I thought you might have calculated something there. Ignore the function if you don't need it.